# /bin/sh: 1: wget: not found python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

i am trying to load a zip file from a URL to my local directory but this error keeps appearing i have upgraded to tensor flow 2.0.0 , i have also install wget package but no luck see image below for better understanding 
[snippet of error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri5uL.png)

Comment: How did you install `wget`? Does it work from the command line?